# Use Guzzle/Middleware with Curl in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, curl, middleware, guzzle, history

viewers! Thanks for your attention.
I'm try to use Guzzle/Middleware :: History with Curl in Laravel 9. I'm trying to keep record for each API called during a job in laravel 9. Somewhere I've used Guzzle and somewhere I've used Curl. For Guzzle I've found this [link](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html#history-middleware) helpful. I wanna use same middle with my curl.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you in advance,
Any suggestion other than this middleware to keep record of all APIs call in laravel Job?

[Guzzle/Middleware::history](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html#history-middleware)

Reason why I'm using History Middleware:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$resposne = $client->request("GET", $endpoint,
    [
        'body' => json_encode($post_data_array),
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
             "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $access_token
         ]
    ]
 );
 $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

above is the code sample how developer is calling APIs using Guzzle/Client. I'll add a history middleware to trace all request made by guzzle client.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the history middleware?

Comment: To save all data like request headers, body, response headers, body etc against all request made in laravel Job WithOUT changing anything in code.

Comment: @apokryfos I've added reason in question.

Comment: No I don't think you have much choice than to do code changes to either convert curl calls to guzzle or put some manual logging in all locations where you use curl

Comment: @apokryfos OK. Seem Like there is no option. If you find anything informative, please share with me. I'm just trying to find a way somehow I can register a middleware with curl.